# Rename [java-ee] to [jakarta-ee]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

[Java EE has been renamed to Jakarta EE](https://mmilinkov.wordpress.com/2018/02/26/and-the-name-is/). It is probably a good idea to rename [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) to [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) as well and then have a synonym called [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) pointing to the new [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) to allow people that are not aware of the name change to still find the tag.

### Update

Currently [both tags are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee+java-ee). It would be a good idea to do *something* about this especially with version 8, which I've seen being referred to as both Java EE 8 and Jakarta EE 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now complete. I've merged the tags and created a synonym, so [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) is now the "main" tag, with [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) as a synonym of it. I also updated the tag wiki excerpt, but the main tag wiki could probably use some update love from an expert.

Per [BalusC's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364137/rename-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee#comment563155_364268), I also merged the [java-ee-web-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-web-profile) into the [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) tag as well.

I'm not sure what to do about the version-specific tags at this point. I'm not opposed to version tags in general. When used judiciously, I think they serve a very important purpose. So I'm *not* going to just merge all of them into the master [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) tag. I think it actually makes sense to just leave the older versions as [java-ee-*], since that is actually the name of the library for those older versions.

If someone wants me to rename the *current* version's version-specific tag (e.g., [java-ee-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-8), because that is actually called Jakarta EE), then please let me know. I can do that easily. But I'll need some evidence, because I don't have any personal knowledge or expertise to draw upon.

Comment: Leave it like it is; Java EE 8 and Jakarta EE 8 [exist in the same sort of epoch](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enterprise-evolution).  That is to say, there was a Java EE 8 before Jakarta EE 8.

Comment: Thanks, @Makoto. Here I thought [Jakarta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta) predated all of it. What do I know? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Jakarta can basically be seen as a box of Java stuff that Apache labeled "Jakarta" :) Yes its a very old tattered box and the bottom layer is filled with many toys nobody plays with anymore.

Answer (score 77):

Definitely in favor of this.

I'd personally only wait until Jakarta EE is "lively" as the current version is still branded "Java EE".

I wonder if it's doable to first make [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) a new synonym of [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) and then once Jakarta EE (9) is released for first time, swap the synonym so that [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) becomes the main tag name.

---

Update January 2020: Jakarta EE has become lively now. See among others:

- https://wildfly.org/news/2019/09/12/WildFly_Jakarta_EE_8/
- https://blog.payara.fish/payara-server-is-jakarta-ee-compatible
- https://tomee.apache.org/ (see intro animation)

Hereby I strongly recommend to make [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) the main tag and [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) a synonym of it.

Comment: agree with waiting. We should only rename this when the term is actually used by people.

Comment: I would also favour adding a new tag and starting with a synonym. I mean the term "j2ee" persists dogmatically to this day, they're not so easily forgotten :/

Comment: DA: Switch now so as to prompt people to start refering to it as [tag:jakarta-ee].

Comment: It is technically doable. There's a button specifically for flipping around synonyms in the mod tools; I don't know whether high-rep users have it too but I assume not since otherwise you'd know about it.

Comment: Payara claims to be Jakarta EE compatible, so I'd say it has become lively by now.

Comment: Yes make [jakarta-ee] the main tag with [java-ee] a synonym of it. Currently it isn't even the other way round yet so these two tags simply coexist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee+java-ee

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422692/rename-jsf-to-jakarta-faces

Answer (score 15):

It seems to be a good idea *at first* but what do we do about the [3000+ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-6+or+java-ee-7+or+java-ee-5+or+java-ee-web-profile+or+java-ee-mvc+or+java-ee-8) tagged [java-ee-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-6), [java-ee-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-7), [java-ee-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-5), [java-ee-web-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-web-profile), [java-ee-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-mvc) or [java-ee-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-8)?

Especially for the ones with a version number + [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee), does it make sense to change [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) to [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee)? For example [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) would seem irrelevant for [java-ee-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee-7) question. And Jakarta EE 7 is not a thing, is it?

In fact, the same probably applies to most [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) questions since they have been asked before the project was given to the Eclipse Foundation. So they are related to the Oracle-supported Java EE and not to Jakarta EE.

As stated on [The Aquarium blog at Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/opening-up-ee-update):

> […] Oracle will continue to support existing Java EE licensees, including licensees moving to Java EE 8.

In fact, I'd even argue that most new [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) questions will still relate to Java EE 7 or Java EE 8 and not Jakarta EE. And people who are actually working on Jakarta EE will know the difference – and hopefully tag it appropriately.

So I'd say that for now, **we should stick with 2 distinct tags**. Jakarta EE is not Java EE.

Comment: [Please burn all these version tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267996/138231). The [java-ee-web-profile] has no use and can be synonymized. The [java-ee-mvc] is referring to the former MVC 1.0, JSR371, which was dropped from Java EE 8 last moment but is candidate to return in Jakarta EE 9. Adjusting the tag name is very difficult as the term [mvc] already exists and isn't referring to the specific framework. As to sticking to 2 distinct tags, **I disagree**, because Java EE experts would in all sudden not become Jakarta EE experts anymore. I for one would not be able to dupehammer them.

Comment: I see your point, but ".. and hopefully tag it appropriately", I'm wondering what percentage of the 3000+ questions are correctly tagged. Most of the tags probably just reflect the version that is used and not specifically relates to the problem.

Comment: Only java-ee-8 needs a synonym (or rename?). The older versions can stay the way they are and need no synonym. I'm already a huge fan of jakarta-ee-8 being a thing rather than java-ee-8, as people will be far less inclined to mis-tag it because they're using java 8.

Comment: @BalusC, the proposal you made on meta.SE was not implemented, so currently we are stuck with the version tags. I personally think they are useful – I'm following [tag:java-8] for instance – but they need to be combined with the main tag for correct use. It seems your main concern is not having the gold badge on [tag:jakarta-ee] yet.

Comment: @Gimby Is jakarta-ee-8 actually a thing? Do they intend to re-release Java EE 8 as Jakarta EE 8 or something like that?

Comment: Main concern is not the lack of gold badge, but the implication that a Java EE expert isn't a Jakarta EE expert at all even though they boil down to exactly the same technology. Missing gold badge is just a consequence thereof.

Comment: @DidierL The Glassfish 5 reference implementation is already released, so java-ee-8 is definitely a thing. But that is also the version which is moved to the Eclipse foundation to be renamed to jakarta-ee-8.