# Tag rename + alias request: [javamail] -> [jakarta-mail]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

In 2019, as part of the transfer of the Java EE projects to Eclipse, the JavaMail specification (and project) was renamed to Jakarta Mail<sup>[1](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/)</sup>. In light of this name change, I'd like to request the following:

1. A tag rename from [javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail) to [jakarta-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-mail)
2. Adding [javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail) as a synonym for [jakarta-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-mail)

Related previous retagging: [Rename [java-ee] to [jakarta-ee]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364137/rename-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail) had an unmerged synonym [javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax.mail) that was created way back in 2011. I merged the two first before renaming the tag. I then renamed the tag to [jakarta-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-mail), and added [javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail) back as a synonym. So now the tag has two synonyms:

[javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail) → [jakarta-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-mail) ← [javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax.mail)